# Why does em unit in CSS not work as expected in this case?

Tags: html, css, letter-spacing

I am learning about letter spacing. I am using the em unit here for letter spacing. The element on which I use the unit does not have any parent except html. But if I change the font size of the HTML, the letter spacing does not change.

At first, the HTML tags were not present in this code. I tried adding them to see if it works. I also tried to set `font-size` at `:root`, but none worked.

```css
html {
  font-size: 2px
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'COUTUREBold';
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 38px;
}

.wide {
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: .5em;
}

.narrow {
  font-size: 48px;
  letter-spacing: -.15em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org//face/couture" type="text/css" />

<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<h1 class="wide">Hello World!</h1>
<h1 class="narrow">Hello World!</h1>
```

Code: https://codepen.io/KAEKrishCodes/pen/ExOYxPY

Comment: I think you may be confusing em and rem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the letter spacing to be affected by the font size of the `html` element, you can use the `rem` unit instead of `em` for letter spacing. The `rem` unit is relative to the root element's font size, which is, in most cases, the html element. You'd want to change all mentions of `em` into `rem` in your code.

For example:

```css
letter-spacing: -.15em;
```

Would become:

```css
letter-spacing: -.15rem;
```

Not sure whether I'm correct on whether this is what you want to do, but I hope it helps.

Comment: This element does not have any parent. So if we use em here, what is it referring to?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure why you would have an element without a parent apart from the body element. Can you not just use the `rem` element, or is the code not working correctly?